# Deployin WebApp on TomEE - Tomcat7, JPA1

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, apache-tomee

I work on my JPS project, and since last Friday I cant re-deploy them.
If I load the *.war file onto the server, it gives no exception, only a "Ok" message.
On server the *.war file unzipped too, but not listed in the web application manager and if u call the right URL, i get an 404 err.

that's the catalina log:

```
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFORMATION: Undeploying context [/umkreissuche-war]
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMATION: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war.war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:31 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFORMATION: ------------------------- localhost -> /umkreissuche-war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:31 PM org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor extract
INFORMATION: Extracting jar: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war.war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:33 PM org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor extract
INFORMATION: Extracted path: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFORMATION: Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=umkreissuche-war/userDataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMATION: Creating Resource(id=umkreissuche-war/userDataSource)
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig deploy
INFORMATION: Configuring PersistenceUnit(name=umkreissuche-jpa, provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider)
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig setJtaDataSource
INFORMATION: Adjusting PersistenceUnit umkreissuche-jpa <jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'umkreissuche-war/userDataSource' from 'null'
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig setNonJtaDataSource
INFORMATION: Adjusting PersistenceUnit umkreissuche-jpa <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'umkreissuche-war/userDataSourceNonJta' from 'null'
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFORMATION: Enterprise application "C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war" loaded.
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFORMATION: Assembling app: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory createDelegate
INFORMATION: PersistenceUnit(name=umkreissuche-jpa, provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider) - provider time 0ms
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
INFORMATION: Undeploying app: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
SCHWERWIEGEND: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/umkreissuche-war]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1524)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1505)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:747)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1668)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:892)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1485)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyResource
INFORMATION: Closing DataSource: umkreissuche-war/userDataSource
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/umkreissuche-war] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/umkreissuche-war]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:896)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1485)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:756)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:750)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:129)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:49)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:116)
    ... 56 more

Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/umkreissuche-war]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1485)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1257)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:896)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:756)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:750)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:129)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:49)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:116)
    ... 56 more

Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error deploying web application archive C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/umkreissuche-war]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1485)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Mai 12, 2015 5:44:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMATION: Deployment of web application archive C:\Users\A22548675\Programme\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\webapps\umkreissuche-war.war has finished in 2,965 ms
```

Used software: [TomEE-Plus 1.7.1](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)

Eclipse-Project-Settings: [image: Eclipse-Project Settings]

Java Build Path: [image]

TomEE version.bat: [image]

Anyone has any idea what the problem is?
Is it any compatibility problem?

Comment: does tomcat show the application as running in app-manager ?

Comment: No it doesnt. The Manager does not list, but the server unzipped the *.war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see from the log, one of the errors is that it is not finding this class: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider . I believe it belongs to the eclipselink api.

The thing is, you have the eclipse link on your build path, so eclipse compiles it and creates the war. But when the app is executing in the server, the app still need those classes to execute what you developed.

What I assume is that you didn't put the eclipselink jar in the libs folder of tomcat.
If any other project is going to use EclipseLink, i suggest that you put the eclipselink jar in the libs folder of tomcat. If not, follow these steps:

Right click on your project and select properties. Then select "Deployment Assembly" and click on "Add.."
Choose "archive from filesystem" and select the eclipselink jar wherever it is in your pc.
By doing this, eclipse will put the jar in your .war, and when the server tries to use any class from EclipseLink, it will find it inside the war.

I don't know if this will make it re-deploy like before, but I assure you that this will solve this class not found error.

Comment: Thx @user3608440, that was the reason.